# Finding all minimum weight matchings

Tags: graph-theory

I know that Edmond's Blossom algorithm can be used to find *a* minimum weight perfect matching for a given graph. However, is there an efficient algorithm known that can find *all* the minimum weight matchings. Or one that can sample uniformly from them all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out Egervary's algorithm which is based on Hungarian method. I'm not sure if it produces all the solutions.